# Levelling two circuits in `minipage`

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4page] {article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0)   to   [open,-*]     (1,0)    coordinate 
            to [nos,l=$x$,-*]  ++ (3,0) 
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Open switch}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
       \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw
          (0,0)   to   [short,-*]     ++(1.5,0)    
           to [short,-*] ++ (2,0)  to
           [short] ++(2,0)
              ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Closed switch}
       \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the two images are not in the same level. Why is it so?

Also how do I bring the first black dot in the first image close to the line breaking segment (`/` shaped position)? Additionally is there any way to make the break segment little longer vertically?

Comment: yes . That is a typo. I am making this correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom-align the minipages with `[b]`.  By default, they are (vertically) center-aligned.  Since the vertical footprints of the two drawings are different, they are not vertically centered.

I also eliminated the extraneous space between minipages, I centered the minipage content, and adjusted the left circuit, to not skew to one side.

I also present a different version of the right-hand circuit.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4page]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0)   to   [open,-*]     (0,0)    coordinate 
            to [nos,l=$x$,-*]  ++ (3,0) 
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Open switch}
    \end{minipage}% <--- AVOIDS EXTRANEOUS SPACE
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
       \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw
          (0,0)   to   [short,*-*]     ++(1.0,0)    
           to [short,*-*] ++ (.5,0)  to
           [short,-*] ++(1,0)
              ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Closed switch}
       \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By changing the switch shape in the left circuit, perhaps it addresses the OP's concern

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4page]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0)   to   [open,-*]     (0,0)    coordinate 
            to [cosw,l=$x$,-*]  ++ (3,0) 
            ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Open switch}
    \end{minipage}% <--- AVOIDS EXTRANEOUS SPACE
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
       \begin{circuitikz}
       \draw
          (0,0)   to   [short,*-*]     ++(1.0,0)    
           to [short,o-o] ++ (.7,0)  to
           [short,-*] ++(1,0)
              ;
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Closed switch}
       \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have added one more question to the previous one. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Please see my revision

Comment: thank you. earlier the caption fell slightly right below the figure.

Comment: Another thing sir as I mentioned in my edit. How do I bring the black dot near `x` in open switch. And how do I enlarge that segment little more?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Perhaps my latest edit answer your concern.